# Нужно пройтись по массиву и сравнить число в массиве с суммой, если больше добавить в массив

Tags: javascript

```
function getBigTransactions(transactions, amount) {
 let res = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++){
     if(transactions[i] > amount){
      res = transactions;
     }
    }
return res;
}

// examples
getBigTransactions([110, 58, 2500, 9000, 462, 256], 100); // ===> [110, 2500, 9000, 462, 256]
getBigTransactions([110, 58, 2500, 9000, 462, 256], 1000); // ===> [2500, 9000]
getBigTransactions([110, 58, 2500, 9000, 462, 256], 9500); // ===> []
```

Comment: Больше суммы чего?

Comment: А, сумма - не как сложение)) Ладно, понятно)

Answer (score 1):

Заменить:

```
res = transactions;
```

на

```
res.push(transactions[i]);
```